# How to scope Vuetify's CSS Reset to the VueJS application only?

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js

I've built a vuejs+vuetify application which will allow people to add it to their site (a widget of sorts).

I've noticed that Vuetify's CSS reset (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/css-reset) isn't scoped to the Vue app and thus applies the reset to the entire document. This is also stated on the above link.

I need a way to scope the reset to only the Vuejs application. I'm currently using webpack for building. I was wondering if there could be a way to append a class like `.v-myapplication` to the reset CSS upon compiling.